# I keep getting "Requested resource not found"

Tags: here-api

I am trying to use the https://wse.ls.hereapi.com/2/findpickups.json api but I always get an error saying

```
    "errors": [
        "Authentication issue",
        "Requested resource not found"
    ],
```

Has it moved to a new location or do i need extra access? I am authenticated and using a bearer token. If I change the token I get a different error so Authentication is not the issue.

Comment: Have you checked your api key?

Answer (score 2):

This looks like the **issue of space** your API request. Please remove all the space in your request as below and try. It should work.

```
https://wse.ls.hereapi.com/2/findsequence.json
?start=Berlin-Main-Station;52.52282,13.37011
&destination1=East-Side-Gallery;52.50341,13.44429
&destination2=Olympiastadion;52.51293,13.24021
&end=HERE-Berlin-Campus;52.53066,13.38511
&mode=fastest;car
&apiKey={YOUR_API_KEY}
```

**Remove the space from the request as below-**

```
https://wse.ls.hereapi.com/2/findsequence.json?start=Berlin-Main-Station;52.52282,13.37011&destination1=East-Side-Gallery;52.50341,13.44429&destination2=Olympiastadion;52.51293,13.24021&end=HERE-Berlin-Campus;52.53066,13.38511&mode=fastest;car&apiKey=YOUR_API_KEY
```

Answer (score 0):

Also, please replace the 'wse' in the url with 'fleet'.
We are changing this in the docs too.

https://fleet.ls.hereapi.com/2/findsequence.json?start=Berlin-Main-Station;52.52282,13.37011&destination1=East-Side-Gallery;52.50341,13.44429&destination2=Olympiastadion;52.51293,13.24021&end=HERE-Berlin-Campus;52.53066,13.38511&mode=fastest;car&apiKey={YOUR_API_KEY}